# xslt remove parent with certain child node's attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I  have  following xml  code

```
<root_el>
 <cell>
  <button id="btn_phone_mvg">
   <text>…</text>
  </button>
 </cell>
 <cell>
  <button id="btn_email_cmb">
   <text>…</text>
  </button>
 </cell>
 <cell>
  <button id="btn_address_mvg">
   <text>…</text>
  </button>
 </cell>
</root_el>
```

And I need to  transform it to another xml where all  **cell**  with child **button** that has **id** with **_mvg** ending will be removed

So  far I've  figured  out that to  remove all cells  with child buttons with certain  id attribute  value will takes this

```
<xsl:template match="cell[button/@id='value']"/>
```

and to  get the last  4 chars of id attribute will take next  XPath expression

```
substring(@id,string-length(@id)-4)
```

But I  don't know how to put this together and get required output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way to match `<cell>` with child `<button>` that has id with last four character equals `_mvg` :

```
<xsl:template match="cell[button[substring(@id,string-length(@id)-3)='_mvg']]"/>
```

Or if available, you can use `ends-with()` function to literally match by string ending :

```
<xsl:template match="cell[button[ends-with(@id, '_mvg')]]"/>
```